# selecting a parent and carrying out

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am very new to javascript so please don't flame me. (or you can if you want I don't mind).

I am trying to remove href anchors within a specific parent which are loaded from another database, while keeping the `css` values. Basically disable the the user from clicking on the link. using `css` to disable pointer events is not an option as the chart has other pointer properties.

Here is the parent html div:

```
<div class="tcchart" id="tc_chart">
   (. . . child divs here)
</div>`
```

Here is the javascript I have tried to come up with. The function `removeattr` itself works across the entire document, but I am struggling to isolate it to just one parent div and its corresponding children.

```
<script>
(function ($) {
    $(window).load(function() {
        $("#tc_chart").parent(function() {
            $('a').removeAttr('href');
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly there is a a-element within the parent div of tc_chart that needs to be removed. Try this

```
var parent = $("#tc_chart").parent();
var link = $(parent).find('a');
$(link).removeAttr('href');
```

Comment: hi steinB. In the console I was getting an error now of "Uncaught ReferenceError: a is not defined" it is highlighting the line which .find(a) is contained. I added ' ' around the a to make it ('a') and the script is working perfect! thank you very much

Comment: Ah sorry! I typed to fast! Yeah you got it :D I edited the answer so you can check it as correct!

Comment: no worries :) I have upvoted and marked as useful, because im a noob though it wont show publicly lol

Answer (score 0):

Iam not sure, if i got you right but this might Help:

```
$("#d1").parent().find("a").removeAttr('href');
```

> In the console I am getting an error now of "Uncaught ReferenceError: a is not defined" it is highlighting the line which .find(a) is contained

this is because you need to set the **a** into **""**